# If I use Dataproc, how does it process real-time streaming data from Apache Hadoop and Spark to Dataproc?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-platform, real-time, dataproc

Has anyone performed migration from On-premise to Google Cloud before?

If I use Dataproc, how does it process real-time streaming data from Apache Hadoop and Spark to Dataproc?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1 :**

I think you can use `Spark Structured streaming` on `dataproc` cluster with `Cloud Pub Sub` :

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/lite/docs/write-messages-apache-spark

Previously `Pub Sub` was only compatible with `Spark DStream` but now you
can use it with `Spark structured streaming`.

**Solution 2 :**

You can think about using `Databricks` on `GCP`, the product is young on `GCP` but offers many features on the top of `Spark` (for batch and streaming).

**Solution 3 :**

If it's not too hard to rewrite your jobs, you can also think about a migration from `Spark` to `Beam` with `Dataflow` runner.

`Beam` with `Dataflow` offers more features regarding `Streaming` and is `serverless` and fully managed on `GCP`.

Comment: for solution 1, can you read/write from regular pubsub (not lite) using spark streaming? sol2 and sol3 are good. unfortunately Beam is not as mature, rich for its python sdk. eg. beam has lack of rich support for many popular IO connector. I see good progress there but it just not there yet